# External API Calls

Tags: typescript, api, networking, httprequest, nestjs

I've built an API to take care of some data. Right now, for testing purposes I'm hosting it in my own computer.

I've made several tests using postman and using localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 as endpoint. But when I tried to call the api using my external ip http://:Port/, it times out and seems as if the request is getting to the API. I have added some logs and no request is getting there.

I forwarded the specific port and created inbound/outbound rules in my firewall to allow the connection and got no luck.

The API was created using NestJS, and I am sending the request from another server which works with lua

I would like to see if anyone could give me a hand.

Thanks in advance

I can provide any code you need

Comment: Can you please add code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.